# Debugging Elixir phoenix.server

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

What I am looking for is some ideas on how to debug `mix phoenix.server`

When I run the command there is no output and it hangs (doesn't finish and show the cmd prompt). I've tried:

```
IEx -S mix phoenix.server
```

this opens up the elixir session but at that point I'm unsure what to do next. I was hoping to see something verbose that showed me where specifically the server start was stopping.  I tried:

```
mix phoenix.server --verbose
```

and that didn't work, of course. At this moment I'm struggling to figure out what the right approach to this is.

Comment: Can you give us more details at which moment this happened ? Is it a new app ? If not, can you give us the potential modifications to the code that might have made this happen ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you need to require the IEx module and place an IEx.pry where you want to debug:

```
defmodule MyModule do
    require IEx

    def my_function do
        IEx.pry
    end
end
```

then run your phoenix server in an IEx context:

```
iex -S mix phx.server
```

Comment: You can also do it inline: `require IEX; IEx.pry`

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your dev.exs file and set your logger level to debug.